# MyMonero mobile app - custom block height

Tags: mymonero, android-wallet, ios-wallet

I don't see any option to set custom block height when restoring wallet via <kbd>Use existing wallet</kbd> button.

Tried MyMonero on Android and iOS. But it's probably all the same..some kind of wrapped web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from support is kinda strange, but they say there is no such option.

In that case I don't understand why we can restore a wallet.

> Hi there,
>
> We are a wallet hosting service, so we only offer the service to host
> any Monero wallet.
>
> You are not able to select a custom block height on our app.

EDIT:

From the support:

> Sometimes when restoring an older wallet, it would need to be manually
> imported and we set the account to scan the blockchain. This takes
> about 90 minutes but thereafter the wallet syncs.
>
> If you’d like us to do that for you, please send us your wallet
> address.

Comment: As far as I know, MyMonero records the wallet creation height for wallets generated with the MyMonero application (desktop, web, or mobile). In case of a wallet generated by 'external' software, MyMonero simply uses zero as wallet creation height.

Comment: @dEBRUYNE I thought this too, but support says it sometimes (not) works - probably when the wallet is created via MyMonero.